# bitbake recipe for copying folder, subfolders for yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I want copy folders and it's content to yocto during image build process. For this process I am using following recipe

```
SUMMARY = "Installation Recipe"
DESCRIPTION = "It installs folder"
HOMEPAGE = ""
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

MY_FILES1 = "/home/jane/d1fold"
MY_FILES2 = "/home/jane/d2fold"

inherit allarch

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/home/root
    cp -R ${MY_FILES1}/* ${D}/home/root
    cp -R ${MY_FILES2} ${D}/home/root
}
FILES_${PN} += " /home/root"
```

But I receive following error *ERROR: QA Issue: weaved: Recipe inherits the allarch class, but has packaged architecture-specific binaries [arch]*. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: You don't want to install something that is on an absolute patch (/home/jane/d1fold). You should provide an archive of d1fold/d2fold, or use `https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/138100/` class. you then need to copy from ${WORKDIR} to ${D}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means that you are trying to install architecture-specific binaries (compiled for x86, arm64 etc), while inheriting allarch class. From [yocto reference manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-classes-allarch):

> The allarch class is inherited by recipes that do not produce architecture-specific output.

This is an obvious contradiction.

What are you trying to do? Creating of recipe that only installs some files seems like wrong architecture decision. And why do you want to inherit allarch?

Answer (score 0):

You are just coping files to `rootfs`. So you no need use `inherit allarch`. remove that and compile.