# Bitbake recipes - Simple file copy

Tags: yocto, bitbake, recipe

I know there is already an answer for my problem here : [bitbake recipe - doing a simple copy of the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163173/bitbake-recipe-doing-a-simple-copy-of-the-image/36164901#36164901)

I also want to copy files but I have this error when trying to compile my recipe :

```
gcc: error: none: No such file or directory
```

Removing the line :

```
inherit allarch
```

Won't cause me any problem, but apparently I need it to copy my files...

Here is my recipe :

```
DESCRIPTION = "My description"
#To prevent the LICENSE field not set
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
PR = "r1"

SRC_URI = "file://main.c \
           file://foo_update.sh \
           file://foo.service \
           "

S = "${WORKDIR}/"

FILES_${PN} += "/script"

inherit allarch

do_compile() {
        ${CC} ${WORKDIR}/main.c -o fooupdate
}


do_install() {
        install -m 0755 -d ${D}${bindir} ${D}/script
        install -m 0755 ${S}/fooupdate ${D}${bindir}
        install -m 0755 ${S}/foo_update.sh ${D}/script
        install -m 0755 ${S}/foo.service ${D}/script
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the solution thanks to this question :
[bitbake recipe for copying folder, subfolders for yocto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47867459/bitbake-recipe-for-copying-folder-subfolders-for-yocto)

Remove `inherit allarch` and instead of using `install -m 0755` for the files you want to copy:

```
install -m 0755 ${S}/foo_update.sh ${D}/script
install -m 0755 ${S}/foo.service ${D}/script
```

Use `cp`:

```
cp ${S}/foo_update.sh ${D}/script
cp ${S}/foo.service ${D}/script
```

Complete recipe :

```
DESCRIPTION = "My description"
#To prevent the LICENSE field not set
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
PR = "r1"

SRC_URI = "file://main.c \
           file://foo_update.sh \
           file://foo.service \
           "

S = "${WORKDIR}/"

FILES_${PN} += "/script"

inherit allarch

do_compile() {
        ${CC} ${WORKDIR}/main.c -o fooupdate
}


do_install() {
        install -m 0755 -d ${D}${bindir} ${D}/script
        install -m 0755 ${S}/fooupdate ${D}${bindir}
        cp ${S}/foo_update.sh ${D}/script
        cp ${S}/foo.service ${D}/script
}
```

Comment: regarding S I receive the following message: Recipe x sets S variable with trailing slash